# Flutter - Firebase Firestore document uid does not exists

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

My db structure is like this:

domain -> user uid -> user data

if I try to add data like this:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(path)
      .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
      .collection(collectionName)
      .add({...});
```

where path is the user domain, the database shows like this:

[image: firestore]

telling me that `The document does not exists, it will not appear in queries or shapshots`. But if I add the same data by auto id like this:

```
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(path)
      .add({...});
```

it works like the second document in picture. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try omitting .collection(collectionName)

Comment: @RajMaheshwari it works but I need to have that collection. I tried with .collection(collectionName).doc().set({...}); but same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at how the documents in this collection are displayed in an italic font in the Firestore console: This means that these documents are only present as "container" of one or more sub-collection but that they are not "genuine" documents.

As a matter of fact by doing

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(path)
      .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
      .collection(collectionName)
      .add({...});
```

You create a doc in the `collectionName` (sub)collection but not in the `path` collection.

On the other hand, with

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(path)
      .add({...});
```

you do create a doc in the `path` collection.

---

So if you need to have a document in the `path` collection AND in the `collectionName` (sub)collection you need to create these two documents and not only the "child" one.

---

**DETAILED EXPLANATIONS:**

Let's take the example of a `doc1` document under the `col1` collection

```
col1/doc1/
```

and another one `subDoc1` under the `subCol1` (sub-)collection

```
col1/doc1/subCol1/subDoc1
```

Actually, **from a technical perspective**, they are not at all relating to each other. They just share a part of their paths but nothing else.

You can very well create `subDoc1` without creating `doc1`.

A side effect of this is that if you delete a document, its sub-collection(s) still exist. Again, the subcollection docs are not really linked to the parent document.

Comment: So as an example, to create the path I must do something like `await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path).doc(firebaseUser.uid).set({});` when the user login for the first time?

Comment: @TaiTech Yes indeed. To be precise you are not going to create a path but a Document. The child document can very well exist without its parent and have its path containing the user ID.

Comment: See the new "DETAILED EXPLANATIONS" section in my answer.

Comment: perfect explanation, thanks